# writing a function with callback in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

reference-url: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function

The below is a way to provide events as a function to to the FullCalendar. How would I write this in a react functional component, I fetch the data using graphql, which is a bit different.

```
 function(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
    req.get('myxmlfeed.php')
      .type('xml')
      .query({
        start: info.start.valueOf(),
        end: info.end.valueOf()
      })
      .end(function(err, res) {

        if (err) {
          failureCallback(err);
        } else {

          successCallback(
            Array.prototype.slice.call( // convert to array
              res.getElementsByTagName('event')
            ).map(function(eventEl) {
              return {
                title: eventEl.getAttribute('title'),
                start: eventEl.getAttribute('start')
              }
            })
          )
        }
      })
```

and here's my current function, it returns a simple array.. how would I implement the callback and callback fail as they mentioned in the documents.

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    const { searchEvents: myEvents } = await searchEvents()
    try {
      const data = myEvents.content.forEach((x) => {
        x.start = new Date(x.start)
        x.end = new Date(x.end)
      })
      setIsPageLoaded(true)
      calendarRef.current.getApi().addEventSource(data)
      return clonedata
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    return true
  }
```

Comment: FWIW, `forEach` doesn't return a value, so `data` will be `undefined`. The documentation says: *"It is the event function’s responsibility to make sure `successCallback` is being called with an array of parsable Event Objects."* How does `fetchData` relate to the first function? Can you provide a more complete example that shows your `fetchData` and the fullcalendar API interact with each other?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend writing a simple `fetchFeed` function that *only* takes care of fetching the data. Using promises, you can avoid the many drawbacks of callback-oriented designs -

```js
function fetchFeed (start, end) {
  return new Promise((success, failure) => {
    req
      .get("myxmlfeed.php")
      .type("xml")
      .query({ start, end })
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err)
          failure(err)
        else
          success(res)
      })
  })
}
```

Now we can call `fetchFeed` with some `startDate` and some `endDate`. The positive result can be processed in `.then(...)` and any error can be addressed in `.catch(...)` -

```js
fetchFeed(startDate, endDate)
  .then(res => {
    // ...
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

Promises received additional support with `async` and `await` syntax that makes writing this kind of program even more natural -

```js
async function updateFeed (...) {
  const res = await fetchFeed(startDate, endDate)
  for (const e of res.getElementsByTagName("event")) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

```js
updateFeed(...).then(console.log).catch(console.error)
```